# 不知說謂, 不三不四 - Meaning In Context?

Tags: mandarin, meaning-in-context

I have heard 不三不四 pronounced (m sarm m sei) in Cantonese. I wonder if Mandarin speakers use this term and in what context? When I asked, someone they supposed that Mandarin speakers might prefer to use something like

> 不知說謂

Which is correct and could anyone supply sample context? Is there a deeper meaning other than the literal sense?

Some one said the phrase is a bit degrading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

不三不四 is a perfectly acceptable term in Mandarin

**Oxford**

> IDIOM
>
> 1 指人 shady
>
> 交不三不四的朋友
>
> make friends with dubious characters

>

> 2 指言词 neither one thing nor the other
>
> 说些不三不四的话
>
> make frivolous remarks

I think you might be mistaking 不知说谓 for 不知所谓 which 汉语大辞典 defines as:

> 不知道该怎么办, 犹言无计可施。

不三不四 is definitely better though!

Comment: You mentioned that one is definitely better than the other. Could you explain why? Also because I do not want to misuse phrases could you explain the context in which the phrases should be used (i.e. when should I use the phrase, would it be demeaning?)

Comment: 不知所谓 is pretty much never used, I wouldn't even try learning it if I were you. 不三不四 doesn't have any un-demeaning parts...anytime you use it will be negative and demeaning.

Comment: Cantonese speakers still say 不知所谓. Its equivalence in Mandarin should be 不知所云 or 不知道说的是什么 which means nobody understands what you said and even you don't know what you've said.